# Quit function for C dice game

Tags: c++, c, exit

Hi this is my first post to stackoverflow i'm creating a Dice Game in C and i'm having difficulty adding a quit feature after each round. once the user makes their prediction the game loop runs again and re-roles 4 new dice values.

I would like to include a function that asks the player if they want to keep going or exit via a (y/n) input.

below is the code for my dice game

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    while(1)
    {
        srand ( time(NULL) );
        int i;
        int DiceR[4]; // Dice Array
        char prediction; //prediction input for high low or equal


        while (1)
        {

          for (i=0; i<1; i++)
    {
        DiceR[0] = (rand()%6) + 1;
        printf("\n%d \n", DiceR[0]);

        DiceR[1] = (rand()%6) + 1;
        printf("%d \n", DiceR[1]);

        DiceR[2] = (rand()%6) + 1;
        printf("%d \n", DiceR[2]);

        DiceR[3] = (rand()%6) + 1;

    }

        printf("\nDo you think the next dice roll will be higher or lower than %d", DiceR[2]);
        printf("\nPlease enter L = Lower E = Equal H = higher or X = Exit:\t");
        scanf("\n%c", &prediction);

        switch(prediction)
    {
    case 'L' : case 'l':
        if (DiceR[3] < DiceR[2]) //Lower
            printf("\ncongrats DiceRoll 4 is %d\n", DiceR[3]); //win
        else
            printf("\nYou lose, the last roll was %d\n", DiceR[3]); //Lose
        break;
    case 'E' : case 'e':
        if (DiceR[3] == DiceR[2]) //Equal
            printf("\ncongrats DiceRoll 4 is %d\n", DiceR[3]); //win
        else
            printf("\nYou lose, the last roll was %d\n", DiceR[3]); //Lose
        break;
    case 'H' : case 'h':
        if (DiceR[3] > DiceR[2]) //Higher
            printf("\ncongrats DiceRoll 4 is %d\n", DiceR[3]); //win
        else
            printf("\nYou lose, the last roll was %d\n", DiceR[3]); //Lose
        break;

    default:
        printf("that value is not recognized");
        break;


    }



        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.   un indent before every closing brace '}'.  That last few code lines (that contain nothing but the closing braces) are very confusing and generally unreadable.  2) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: are you familiar with the `toupper()` macro, available in the `ctype.h` header file?  You could greatly simplify your code by using that macro before entering the `switch()` code block

Comment: the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are values with no basis.  for instance, the 4 and 6 in the posted code.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statements to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: the code block beginning with: `for (i=0; i<1; i++)` will be executed exactly once.  In other words, the `for()` statement is not needed, it just clutters the code

Comment: the outer `while(1)` loop does nothing, and would, if executed, result in multiple calls to `srand()`, however that function should not be called more than once.  The outer `while(1)` loop does nothing, and just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.  Suggest removing the outer `while(1)` loop

Comment: after the above 'code clutters' are removed, the variable `i` is not used, suggest removing that variable.

Comment: do not `#include` header files that are not used,  In this case do not include `math.h` nor `string.h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to include a function that asks the player if they want
>   to keep going or exit via a (y/n) input.

A function which asks the user at the start of each roll to continue or stop

```
int cont()
{
    char ch;
    printf("\n want to continue or stop? y/n : \n");
    scanf(" %c",&ch); //note a space before %c to consume white spaces
    if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
        return 0; //if yes i.e, 'y' return 0
    return 1; //else return 1
}
```

---

just check for the return value of function at the start of each roll this way :

*(follow the comments to understand)*

```
//#include .......

int cont()
{
    char ch;
    printf("\n want to start/continue? y/n : \n");
    scanf(" %c",&ch);
    if(ch=='y'||ch=='Y')
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main ()
{
    int flag=0; //initialize flag with a value of zero

    while(1) //first while loop
    {
        //srand and other variables initialization

        while (1) //second while loop
        {    
          //don't use if(cont()) here....

          //for loop

          //printing and scanning prediction

            switch(prediction)
            {

             //all other cases........              

             case 'X': case 'x': //you seem to have forgotten mentioning this case :)
                 flag=1;
                 break;

             //default case
            }


            //use it here instead sso that you'd get it at the end of each turn 
            if(cont()) //function call : here you ask user for y/n input
            {
              //if user enter no i.e, 'n', then you enter the if block
               flag=1;
               break;
            }

            if (flag==1) //checking for flag; useful when user enters 'X'
            break; //break out of first while loop
        }

        if(flag==1) //checking for flag
            break; //break out of second while loop
    }

}
```

Comment: @LukeTomkins if you have any doubts feel free to ask :) , if this is not what you want then do let me know

Comment: Hi sorry for the late reply this is exactly what I was looking for thanks. I've implemented the 'int cont()' function but I would like to have it run after every round. The continue question pops up when the application launches. Any idea how i could tweak this?

Comment: @LukeTomkins pleasure helping you.. if this solved the problem then mark it as accepted :) ... sure that can be avoided ... i'll edit the answer

Comment: @LukeTomkins just use the `if(cont())` block after the `switch()` in inner loop instead of using it above the `switch()`... i've edited have a look! did it solve?? :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a flag for this before the first `while`, like, `bool running = true;`, set it to false when/where you wanted to exit, then check that in the `while`s instead of an infinite loop.

Comment: so set up a 'bool running = true' at the start and then further down create a if statement to turn 'running' to false. i want the app to loop infinitely but i want it to stop in between loops to check if the player wants another turn

Answer (score 0):

You can create a flag and use the condition `(flag==true);` to keep the code running while the user wants it

Answer (score 0):

here is a 'corrected' version of the code.

Note, printing the values of the calls to `rand()` might not be the best way, especially as the user plays the game awhile and recognizes the pattern(s)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//#include <string.h>
//#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_OF_DICE (4)
#define MAX_DICE_VALUE (6)

int main ()
{
    srand ((unsigned) time(NULL) );
    int DiceR[ NUM_OF_DICE ]; // Dice Array
    char prediction; //prediction input for high low or equal


    while (1)
    {
        for( size_t i=0; i<NUM_OF_DICE; i++)
        {
            DiceR[i] = (rand()%MAX_DICE_VALUE) + 1;
            printf("\n%d \n", DiceR[i]);
        }

        printf("\nDo you think the next dice roll will be higher or lower than %d", DiceR[2]);
        printf("\nPlease enter L = Lower E = Equal H = higher or X = Exit:\t");

        if( 1 != scanf("\n%c", &prediction) )
        { // then scanf failed
            perror( "scanf for inputting prediction failed");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        prediction = (char)toupper(prediction);

        if( 'X' == prediction )
        {
            return 0;
        }

        switch(prediction)
        {

            case 'L' :
                if (DiceR[3] < DiceR[2]) //Lower
                    printf("\ncongrats DiceRoll 4 is %d\n", DiceR[3]); //win
                else
                    printf("\nYou lose, the last roll was %d\n", DiceR[3]); //Lose
                break;

            case 'E' :
                if (DiceR[3] == DiceR[2]) //Equal
                    printf("\ncongrats DiceRoll 4 is %d\n", DiceR[3]); //win
                else
                    printf("\nYou lose, the last roll was %d\n", DiceR[3]); //Lose
                break;

            case 'H' :
                if (DiceR[3] > DiceR[2]) //Higher
                    printf("\ncongrats DiceRoll 4 is %d\n", DiceR[3]); //win
                else
                    printf("\nYou lose, the last roll was %d\n", DiceR[3]); //Lose
                break;

            default:
                printf("input must be 'L' or 'H' or 'E' or 'X'\n");
                break;
        } // end switch
    }
} // end function: main
```